# How do i sum up value from multiple rows from one table base on a condition and insert the sum up value to different table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to select a value from a table(**daily_interest_tbl**) and sum up the value base on the customer ID and insert the sum up value and the customer ID to a different table (**monthly_tbl**).

The query will be call in an event to run end of every month.
[image]

[image]

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
INSERT INTO monthly_tbl (NAMES_OF_THE_RESPECTIVE_COLUMNS_COMMA_SEPARATED)
(
  SELECT daily_interest_tbl.customerID, SUM(daily_interest_tbl.NAME_OF_THE_VALUE_YOU_WANT_TO_SUM_UP)
  FROM daily_interest_tbl
  GROUP BY customerID
)
```